# Debugging Indentation error on Python Parser of ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

Would anyone please help me find out why I get an indentation error in line 3

```
def calc(f1,f2,f3):
remove_list = ['01ST', '02ND', '03RD', '04TH', '05TH', '06TH', '07TH', '08TH', '09TH']
    if f2 in remove_list:
        f2 = f2.replace('0','')
    else:
        f2 = f2
f1 = f1.strip()
f2 = f2.strip()
f3 = f3.strip()     
f1 = str(f1).replace('.0','')
x = f1+' '+f2+' '+f3
return x
```

THe function is simply supposed to evaluate the if statement then concatenate fields f1, f2 and f3. Do I need to end the if statement somehow?

Comment: why do you need to set f2=f2? This seems redundant. Just remove the else statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You need to indent the function you're defining.
2. Don't further an indent for an `if` statement until after the `if` statement.

   `def calc(f1,f2,f3):`

   ```
       remove_list = ['01ST', '02ND', '03RD', '04TH', '05TH', '06TH', '07TH', '08TH', '09TH']
       if f2 in remove_list:
           f2 = f2.replace('0','')
       else:
           f2 = f2
       ...
   ```